# Compile error with C++ Linked List creation. Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am attempting to create a linked list RecipeBook. I need to **create a method add, which takes a Recipe object parameter and adds it to the end of the linked list**.

When compile on my mac I receive the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Recipe::Recipe()", referenced from:
      RecipeBook::add(Recipe) in assign6-sendOnline-d41d53.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I compile on my schools linux server I receive:

```
/tmp/ccFZOs7z.o: In function `RecipeBook::add(Recipe)':
/home/cs/dbrinkley/csci133/assign6/assign6.cpp:30: undefined reference to `Recipe::Recipe()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I feel I have tried all sorts of things, but whatever it is I just can't find it. I am not sure if I am passing the object parameter in incorrectly or what.

When I remove the function call on rb in the main, then the file compiles. Also when I remove the whole add method defintion, the file compiles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Recipe {
  public:
    std::string name;
    std::string bodyText;

    Recipe();
    Recipe(std::string inName, std::string inBodyText){
      name = inName;
      inBodyText = bodyText;
    };

    Recipe *next, *prev;
};


class RecipeBook {
  private:
    Recipe *head, *tail;    

  public:
    RecipeBook(){
      head = NULL;
      tail = NULL;
    }

    void add(Recipe r){
      Recipe *temp = new Recipe;
      *temp = r;
      if(head == NULL){
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        temp = NULL;
      } else {
        tail->next = temp;
        temp->prev = tail;
        tail = temp;
      }
    }
};



int main(){
  RecipeBook rb;
  Recipe r1("hamburger", "cook it");

  rb.add(r1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new Recipe` creates and *default construct* a new `Recipe` object. To be able to default construct an object, you must have a default constructor *implemented*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Explanation of error

You declare that `Recipe::Recipe()` exists here:

```
class Recipe {
  public:
    std::string name;
    std::string bodyText;

    Recipe();
```

But you don't actually define it, so the compiler expects the definition to come from an external source (like a separately linked cpp file).

#### Solving this problem

Fixing it is really easy. Just add a definition:

```
class Recipe {
  public:
    std::string name;
    std::string bodyText;

    Recipe() {} // Recipe has a definition now
```

Or, even better, just default the definition:

```
class Recipe {
   public:
    std::string name;
    std::string bodyText;

    Recipe() = default;
```

Defaulting the definition will make the constructor trivial, which makes it easier for the compiler to perform certain optimizations.

Comment: Or just `Recipe() = default;` in the class declaration. Then the constructor will also stay *trivial*, which no user defined constructor is - even an empty one.